# User inputs information into text box which makes allows user to select multiple words and creates different Titles based on the selections

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am gaining user input from four different areas and I want to take those options and convert them to an array which will loop through and display different variations of the words selected. The problem I am having is that the array will not cycle through the variables when passed through it unless they are already pre-defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title Generation Module</title>
<script src="title.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="find.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="generate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="check.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--> <!-- Leaving for future usage not needed at this point -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="title.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Title Generation Module</h1>   
<h2>Example</h2>
    <p>When you type into Core Words you want to put words that cannot change such as: Logitech
        </br> For Word Combinations you want to use words such as: Brand New or Power Adaptor
        </br> For Swapped Words you might want to use: Gaming instead of Performance or vice versa
        </br> For Synonyms you want to use words that mean the same thing such as for = 4 or at = @</p>
<h3>Core Words</h3>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="newCore"/>
        <button  id="addCore">Insert</button>
        <label for="coreContain">Select as many as you like:</label>
        <select id="coreContain" name="coreContain" multiple></select>
        <button id="checkCore" onclick="checkCore()">Insert into Array</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#addCore").click(function()
            {
                $("#coreContain").append('<option value="' + $("#newCore").val() + '">' + $("#newCore").val() + '</option>');
            });
        });

     $('#coreContain option').each(
        function(c)
        {
            $(this).val(c).text('option: ' + c);
        });

    var coreOptions = new Array();

     $('form').submit(
        function()
        {
            $('#coreContain > option:selected').each(
            function(i)
            {
                coreOptions[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            //window.alert(coreOptions);
            return false;
        });

</script>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

<!-- User inputs Word Combinations -->
<h3>Word Combinations</h3>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="newCombo"/>
        <button  id="addCombo">Insert</button>
        <label for="comboContain">Select as many as you like:</label>
        <select id="comboContain" name="comboContain" multiple></select>
        <button id="checkCombo" onclick="checkWordCombo()">Insert into Array</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#addCombo").click(function()
            {
                $("#comboContain").append('<option value="' + $("#newCombo").val() + '">' + $("#newCombo").val() + '</option>');
            });
        });

     $('#comboContain option').each(
        function(c)
        {
            $(this).val(c).text('option: ' + c);
        });

    var comboOptions = new Array();

     $('form').submit(
        function()
        {
            $('#comboContain > option:selected').each(
            function(i)
            {
                comboOptions[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            //window.alert(comboOptions);
            return false;
        });

</script>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
<!-- User inputs words that can swap -->
<h3>Words that can be Swapped</h3>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="newSwap"/>
        <button  id="addSwap">Insert</button>
        <label for="swapContain">Select as many as you like:</label>
        <select id="swapContain" name="comboSwap" multiple></select>
        <button id="checkSwap" onclick="checkSwap()">Insert into Array</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#addSwap").click(function()
            {
                $("#swapContain").append('<option value="' + $("#newSwap").val() + '">' + $("#newSwap").val() + '</option>');
            });
        });

     $('#swapContain option').each(
        function(c)
        {
            $(this).val(c).text('option: ' + c);
        });

    var swapOptions = new Array();

     $('form').submit(
        function()
        {
            $('#swapContain > option:selected').each(
            function(i)
            {
                swapOptions[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            //window.alert(swapOptions);
            return false;
        });

</script>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

<!-- User inputs words that can be use as Synonyms -->
<h3>Words that can be used as Synonyms</h3>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="newSyn"/>
        <button  id="addSyn">Insert</button>
        <label for="synContain">Select as many as you like:</label>
        <select id="synContain" name="comboSyn" multiple></select>
        <button id="checkSyn" onclick="checkSyn()">Insert into Array</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#addSyn").click(function()
            {
                $("#synContain").append('<option value="' + $("#newSyn").val() + '">' + $("#newSyn").val() + '</option>');
            });
        });

     $('#synContain option').each(
        function(c)
        {
            $(this).val(c).text('option: ' + c);
        });

    var synOptions = new Array();

     $('form').submit(
        function()
        {
            $('#synContain > option:selected').each(
            function(i)
            {
                synOptions[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            //window.alert(synOptions);
            return false;
        });

</script>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
<button onclick="generate_title()">Generate Titles</button>
<button onclick="displayList()">Click Me</button>
<script>
    function displayList()
    {
        alert(coreOptions+ " " +comboOptions +" " +swapOptions+ " " +synOptions);
    }
</script>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

External Javascript

```
var check = ["Facebook", "MySpace", "Twitter"];
//document.getElementById("coreOptions");
//var checkX = check.splice(" ");
var checkY = document.getElementById("swapOptions");
var input_keywords = 
 [
    [check, check],
    //[checkY,checkY],
    ["Cordless-","Wireless"],
    ["Rechargeable+"],
    ].filter(function(item){
    return item.length <= 80;
    });


        /*[
           ["Men", "Women", "Unisex"],
           ["1", "2", "3", "fourrrrrrrrrr"],
           ["Candy Color"],
           ["Spring"],
           ["Ski+"],
           ["Crochet"],
           ["Hip-hop"],
           ["Hat Beanie-"],
           ["One Size+"]].filter(function(item)
           {
               return item.length <= 80;
           });
        */

        /*
        var input_keywords = [
                ["Women Men", "Men Women", "Unisex Women Men", "Unisex Men Women", "Unisex", "Womens Mens", "Mens Womens", "Unisex Womens Mens", "Unisex Mens Womens"],
                ["Fashion", "Trendy", "Stylish", "Korea Style"],
                ["Candy Color"],
                ["Spring", "Summer", "Winter"],
                ["Ski"],
                ["Crochet", "Knit", "Knitted"],
                ["Elastic", "Strechable"],
                ["Hip-hop", "Dance"],
                ["Hat", "Cap", "Beanie", "Hat Cap", "Hat Beanie", "Hat Cap Beanie"],
                ["One Size"]
            ].filter(function(item){
                return item.length <= 80;
            });
        */
    var limit_count = 24;
    var max_char_per_title = 80;
    var sub_library = ["for=4", "you=u", "at=@", "two=2", "with=w", "adapter=adpt", "Monokini=Mono 9"].map( function (item)
        { return item.split("=");});
function calc_length(title)
    {
        return (title
        .join(" ") + " ")
        .replace("- ", " ")
        .replace("+ ", " ")
        .replace("* ", " ")
        .replace("  ", " ")
        .replace("\" ", " ")
        .replace(" \"", " ")
        .length - 1;

    }
function get_all_titles(keywords)
    {
        var result_titles = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i ++)
        {
            var word_count = keywords[i].length;
            var words = keywords[i];
            var previous_count = result_titles.length;
            if (previous_count == 0)
                {
                    previous_count = word_count;
                    for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < word_count; sub_ii++)
                    {
                        result_titles[sub_ii] = [];
                        result_titles[sub_ii][i] = words[sub_ii];
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                    for (var sub_i = 0; sub_i < word_count; sub_i++)
                    {
                        for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < previous_count; sub_ii++)
                            {
                                if (result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] == undefined)
                                    {
                                        result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] = result_titles[sub_ii                                          ].slice();
                                    } 
                                result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii][i] = words[sub_i];
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
        return result_titles;
    }

function substitute(title)
    {
        for (var subs_idx = 0 ; subs_idx < sub_library.length; subs_idx++)
        {
            var index = title.indexOf(sub_library[subs_idx][0]);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                title[index] = sub_library[subs_idx][1];
            }  
        }
        return title;
    }

function shorten_title_length(titles)
    {
        var result = [];
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < titles.length; i++)
            {
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                {
                    //substitute with the word in library
                    titles[i] = substitute(titles[i]);
                    // still too long, remove possible words.
                    if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        var words = titles[i];
                        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
                        { 
                            if (words[word_idx].indexOf("/") == (words[word_idx].length - 1))
                            {
                                titles[i] = titles[i].splice(word_idx, 1);
                            }

                        }
                        titles[i] = words
                    }
                }
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) <= max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        result[count] = titles[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                else
                {
                    console.log(titles[i].join(" \ "));
                }
            }
            return result;
    }

function change_forward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "-")
            {
                if (word_idx != words.length - 1)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx + 1];
                    words[word_idx + 1] = tmp;
                    word_idx ++;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function change_backward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "+")
            {
                if (word_idx != 0)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx - 1];
                    words[word_idx - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function finalize(titles)
    {
        for (var title_idx = 0 ; title_idx < titles.length; title_idx++)
        {
            for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < titles[title_idx].length; word_idx++)
            {
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '+')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '-')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '/')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '"')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '*')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
            }
        }
        return titles;
    }

function generate_title()
    {

        var all_titles = get_all_titles(input_keywords);
        //Check keyword files provided by the user, that optional sub words are at least 24
        if (all_titles.length < limit_count)
        {
            alert("not enough different titles");
        }
        //check total char per title
        all_titles = shorten_title_length(all_titles);
        // substitute half randomly.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = substitute(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position backward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_backward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position forward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_forward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        all_titles = finalize(all_titles);
        // evaluate.....
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(all_titles[i].join(" \ "));
            console.log(all_titles[i].length);
            alert(all_titles);

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share a plunkr or even a drawing- not sure I understand what you are trying to do

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mvL8k2a4/1/